# MongoDB aggregation, find non unique double fields if those existed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB collection with something like this:

```
{ "parentId": "5d304431fdfd02eacf7d5dce", "name": "test" }
{ "parentId": "5d304431fdfd02eacf7d5dce", "name": "test" }
{ "parentId": "5d304431fdfd02eacf7d5dce", "name": "test" }
{ "name": "test"}
{ "name": "test"}
{ "parentId": "5d02033efdfd02580e04570e", "name": "test4" }
{ "parentId": "5d02033efdfd02580e04570e", "name": "test5" }
{ "parentId": "5d02033efdfd02580e04570e", "name": "test5" }
```

I need to find all non-unique bunch of 2 fields values: "parentId" & "name".
But the main problem - there are documents without one of needed fields(exemple).

I`m stuck on query:

```
db.default.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "parentId": "$parent",
        "name": "$name"
      },
      "uniqueIds": {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

So, I would like to get on finish:

```
{ "parentId": "5d304431fdfd02eacf7d5dce", "name": "test", count: "3" }
{ "parentId": "5d02033efdfd02580e04570e", "name": "test5", count: "2" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get you expected output:

```
db.default.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "parentId":{
                $exists: true
            },
            "name":{
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "parentId": "$parentId",
                "name":"$name"
            },
            "parentId":{
                $first: "$parentId"
            },
            "name":{
                $first: "$name"
            },
            "count":{
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "count":{
                $gt:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }   
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{ "parentId" : "5d02033efdfd02580e04570e", "name" : "test5", "count" : 2 }
{ "parentId" : "5d304431fdfd02eacf7d5dce", "name" : "test", "count" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine. Since you want to filter out results whose `parentId` don't exist, so just `$match` on first stage of aggregate and continue with your query as it is.

```
db.default.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      parentId: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        parentId: "$parentId",
        name: "$name"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

in aggregate like add match clause.

example:

```
$match: {
   "name": {$exists: true}, "parentId" : {$exists: true}
 }
```